# Monitor throughput bandwidth GCE

Tags: monitoring, bandwidth, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Im new to Google Cloud Platform and have set up a VM that is working. Im expecting that there will be a significant amount of bandwidth use through this server.

Id like to know what the bandwidth usage is so that I can anticipate what the impact might be to this project over time.

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

You could track the bandwidth usage in term of billing by enabling the daily billing export [1] that will populate a CSV or Json in your Bucket (storage) with the a well detailed breakdown of your charges.
[1] https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-file